# 1, 2, 3, 10, ... Another find-the-next-number-in-the-sequence puzzle

Tags: mathematics, pattern, number-sequence, sequence

Can you spot the pattern and continue the following sequence?

1, 2, 3, 10, 12, 16, 25, 37, 55, 81, 100, ...

Hints:

> It is based on another, well-known sequence

> The first number is missing because I'm not sure how to write it.

Comment: I'm glad you're eager to contribute a puzzle here, but this type of bare number sequence puzzle generally doesn't fare well. You may want to read [Number-Sequence Puzzles: What (Not) To Do?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5712) for some guidance on how to turn a number-sequence challenge into an interesting puzzle.

Comment: If I ask any AI, it says some nonsense and then "So the next term in the sequence is 132."

Comment: @RonchenLuo I tried that too. Glad to know an AI can't figure it out :)

Comment: if I do it in parallel 1 2 3 4 5 6 with 1 2 3 10 12   is very similar with Fibonacci sequence the  4th number is the sum of the all left number in the firs succession but after I don't know how to continue.  M I near ?

Comment: @IlCorsaroNero The part "similar with Fibonacci sequence" is alright. The rest, not so much.

Comment: Can you give another hint ? I have observed that there are a lot of common numbers with Fibonacci sequence  is the other ones if u make the square root "converge by increasing one number."

Comment: the other idea that I have is related with roman number. M I near ?

Comment: @IlCorsaroNero No roman numerals. So the Fibonacci sequence (minus the first number) is 1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89,144. You just have to match each number to the sequence given. It's not complicated, just a single trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer

I think that is something like this the first three number  are the same of Fibonacci series  and start from the fourth I have to change the base start from base 5  and increase by one so the missing number in this case I have to convert 233 from decimale base to thirteen base the result is 14c

Comment: Actually, you don't start from the fourth. You start immediately. The 1 is in base 2, the 2 is in base 3, etc. That's why the first number is missing, because how do you write something in base 1?

Comment: In the [Unary numeral system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_numeral_system), 1 is written as `1`.